# Copy filename of file selected in Finder to clipboard using Automator with Applescript

Tags: applescript, automator

I'm trying to create an Automator Application that begins with selecting a Finder item.

Before continuing I would like to copy the filename only, *not* the pathname to the clipboard.

How can I do that?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: When using the **Automator** _workflow_, will you only be selecting one _file_ at a time in **Finder** to be processed and therefore only needing the _name_ of  one _file_ to be placed on the _clipboard_? Also, when you say _name_, does this also include it's _file extension_?

Comment: Hey thanks for your response.
Yes it would only be one file at a time needed.
Ideally it would be minus the extension :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To place the *name* of the **Finder** *item* without its *extension* onto the **clipboard**, you will need to add a **Run AppleScript** *action* with the following *example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
on run {input, parameters}
    
    set fileName to first item of input
    
    tell application "System Events" to ¬
        tell disk item (fileName as text) to ¬
            set {theName, theExtension} to ¬
                {name, name extension}
    
    if theExtension is not "" then
        set theName to ¬
            text 1 thru -((count theExtension) + 2) ¬
                of theName
        set the clipboard to theName
    else
        set the clipboard to theName
    end if
    
    return input
    
end run
```

The `return input` in the *example* **AppleScript** *code* will pass the **Finder** *item(s)* onto the next *action* in the *workflow*.

---

**Note:**

As coded it will only place the *name* of the first selected **Finder** *item*, without its *extension*, onto the **clipboard**, as per your comment.

Comment: That's perfect - Thanks very much.

After working on the Automator some more I see that I need 2 actions done from a single file selection input by the user.

So it would be:
Up to this point a file selection window is open in the app I'm running this for.
I'd like to:

1 Ask For Finder Items
2 Select File
3 Copy Path Name
4 Go to Folder within the open application and paste and go with pathname
5 Refer back to the selected Finder item in point 1
6 Place the name of the Finder item without its extension onto the clipboard - as per the apple script.

Is it possible to refer back?

Comment: KaBro, I just want to say that my answer actually answered the question you asked, however, your additional needs in a comment to my answer changes the scope of the question, so to speak. That's not really how things are done here! Please post a new question with a screen shot of the _workflow_ (preferred) or full description of the workflow and what your needs/requirements are that your are unable to figure out.

Comment: Sure will post another one!
Thanks very much for your help :)